# Kivy: Data not being sent from android phone

Tags: android, python, sockets, network-programming, kivy

I am creating a small app in kivy for android which will send a text data to my laptop. I have created a network using my router.

The code for the client app is

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import socket

Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
                id: t1
                size_hint_y: 75
        Button:
                text: "send data"
                font_size: 75
                size_hint_y: 25
                on_press: root.send_data()
''')

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self):
                super(RootWidget, self).__init__()
                host="10.0.0.5"
                port=3000
                self.s=socket.socket()
                self.s.connect((host, port))
        def send_data(self):
                msg=str(self.ids.t1.text)
                encoded_msg=bytes(msg, "utf-8")
                self.s.send(encoded_msg)

class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
                return RootWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

The server runs in the terminal of my PC...its code is

```
import socket

host="10.0.0.5"
port=3000
s=socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)

def server():
        while True:
                c, addr=s.accept()
                print("\nconnection successful with "+str(addr)+"\n\n")
                data=c.recv(1024)
                decoded_data=data.decode("utf-8")
                if not decoded_data:
                        print("connection with "+ str(addr)+ " broken\n")
                else:
                        print("-> "+ decoded_data + "\n")

server()
```

When I run the server and the client app on my laptop I get the correct result

```
connection successful with ('10.0.0.5', 36719)


-> hello

^C
```

I made the apk file of my client app using Buildozer. When I try to run the app from my android phone it gets connected but when I type a text in the textinput and press the 'send data' button the the app terminates and the output that I get on the server terminal is

```
connection successful with ('10.0.0.6', 35711)


connection with ('10.0.0.6', 35711) broken

^C
```

I am not able to figure out the problem in running the client app on android...Need help in fixing this

Comment: Do you need a permission to access the network? And do you have that permission?

Comment: ya I have enabled that permission thats why it is getting connected to the server

Comment: This looks like an inbound firewall rule on the android. That is why it breaks after accepting the connection from the phone and attempts to send back data.

Answer (score 2):

In your file `buildozer.spec` change

```
#android.permissions = INTERNET
```

which is currently commented out with a hash sign,
to this:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```